# QMap function: check it contains isbn number

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I am trying to write a function to determine if a given isbn number is in a `QMap` list, I see I'm not using `contains` properly, not sure if this would even logically work?

```
bool TextbookMap::foundTextBook(QString isbn) const {
    bool found = false;
    ConstIterator itr = constBegin();
    for ( ; itr != constEnd(); ++itr)
    {
         if (itr.contains(isbn))
             found = true;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: That's a poor implementation as you continue searching even though you have found the entry.  Make the `for` loop condition `itr != constEnd() && !found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to iterate the map - this is what `contains()` already does for you. Simply use

```
bool TextbookMap::foundTextBook(const QString& isbn) const {
   return contains(isbn);
}
```

(I assume that you have derived `TextbookMap` from `QMap`)

The below code prints

```
false
true
```

---

```
class Textbook {
};

class TextbookMap : public QMap<QString, Textbook*> {
public:
    bool foundTextBook(const QString& isbn) const;
};

bool TextbookMap::foundTextBook(const QString& isbn) const {
    return contains(isbn);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    TextbookMap map;
    map.insert("1234", new Textbook());
    map.insert("5678", new Textbook());
    qDebug() << map.foundTextBook("01234");
    qDebug() << map.foundTextBook("1234");

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, you do not even need to implement a separate method - you could also use `map.contains()` directly. But it depends on your concrete requirements whether it makes sense to encapsulate the `contains()` method like this. On a side note, I usually try to avoid deriving from container classes and use delegation instead.

Comment: 1st line of class definition for TextbookMap is:

Comment: class TextbookMap : public QMap<QString, Textbook*>

Comment: I have adjusted the sample - at the end, this is not relevant for the general design of the `foundTextBook()` method. I could also have used any other type like `QString` for the value type of the map.

Comment: Bonus points for advising not to derive from container classes -- that's a **very good** advice and it would deserve a much more prominent place in the response :)